# Memory allocation in cuda c

Tags: cuda

when we want to allocate memory on device we use following syntax:

```
float *device_array;
error = cudaMalloc((void *)&device_array,
   sizeof(float) * N);
```

what is that "&" for?
we dont use it in cudaMemCpy.

Comment: To *change* the pointer value inside cudaMalloc, it must be passed by address, rather than by value. C has no pass by reference symantics and the CUDA APIs are all notionally C APIs.

Comment: "cudaMalloc((void *)device_array, sizeof(float)*N);" since device_array is a pointer , isnt (void *)device_array an address? @talonmies

Comment: No, it isn't and address, it is a value, and it is not possible to change the value at the caller's scope like that. Don't confuse assigning a value to a pointer and pointer indirection. They are not the same thing

Comment: I feel dumb talkin to you ,thanks a bunch @talonmies